# Google Analytics - How to replace %20 with <space> in Custom Report

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a custom report in google analytics. There is a problem in custom variable's value. In Google Analytics custom report, I see that **space** is replaced by **%20** in my custom variable's value.

For example,

My custom variable value should be:-

> basic HTML/asking help

But, I see the following in Google Analytics:-

> basic%20HTML%2Fasking%20help

**space** is replaced by **%20** and **slash (/)** is replaced by **%2F**.

In my **google analytics script**, the value of the custom variable is displaying fine without %20 and %2F.

The main problem is in **google analytics custom report**.

Any idea why this happens and what is the solution?

Thank You.

Comment: Doesn't instill much confidence: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=2cdb3ec0be32e078&hl=en

Comment: It seems to be google analytics bug. I tried to create 'search and replace' filter for the workaround following this link:- http://www.chrisabernethy.com/google-analytics-how-to-replace-20-with-a-space/. But, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and I don't believe there is a fix for it yet.

- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=2cdb3ec0be32e078&hl=en
- http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=6daf7b64bb0bd442&hl=en

As a workaround, you might try just using dashes when you're naming your custom variables, e.g. 'basic-html-asking-help'. These will not be encoded and should be more legible.

Comment: It's a known issue, and they likely won't fix it, because it would break code relying on the encoded spaces.